# How do I statistically compare variances of random effects obtained from two lmer models in R?

Tags: mixed-model, variance

I have these three models where I am testing if time spent on the surface by fish (dependent variable) depends on their age (fixed effect), with fish groupID as the random effect. LH, RH (control) and SH are 3 selection lines.

```
fitLH <- lmer(time ~ Age + (1|GroupID), data=LH)
fitRH <- lmer(time ~ Age + (1|GroupID), data=RH)
fitSH <- lmer(time ~ Age + (1|GroupID), data=SH)
```

After running these models, I get the variance of random effects i.e. for GroupID  (Intercept) and the residual variance. I am interested in comparing the variances obtained from models run for LH and SH lines with that obtained from the model run for RH (control) line. Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Comment: Sounds to me like this is a case of nested random effects as fish are clustered by both group and selection line. Empirically, it may be hard to get great random effect estimates for selection line since there are only 3 levels of that. Regardless, it doesn't seem valid to treat these as three separate samples to which three separate models are fit. In other words, the data generation (how you came to observe the `time` variable) is (at least theoretically) impacted by selection line, so your inferential model should reflect that generation process somehow

Comment: I have constructed models like said where I have considered nested random effects. My question is different. I want to estimate the within- and between-group variances (to account for behavioural variability and plasticity) for each selection line separately and that can only be achieved by separate models for each line. Hence, the above three separate models. The variance due to group ID is the between-group variance and the residual variance is the within-group variance. I want to compare these values across three lines. Is there a way?

Comment: I guess that I don't follow why the nested random effects are still incorrect. You will get variance estimates for the line, group, and the interaction. You can test whether the variance for lines, for example, is different from zero. If this variance was not, then this would mean there's no difference between lines. From a study design perspective, is it really more accurate that you should think about your study as 3 different parts (i.e., separate models) rather than 1 study with different factors (i.e., a single model)?